# Set XFF header to last appended IP Nginx

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a seemingly simple problem that I can't figure out.

I have a micro-service that validates the Customers IP against a whitelist. The problem is that I have a LoadBalancer (ALB) and a reverse proxy (Nginx) in-front of this MicroService.

What I am using in the MicroService is the last IP in the XFF (X-Forwarded-For) header.

But this opens me up for XFF injections. Because I trust the ALB in-front of my proxy, and know it is the first hop in the network, I want to use the IP it append to the XFF header, and overwrite the header completely. ( I want to do this in NginX)

How would I go about extracting the last value in the XFF header in Nginx, and then overwriting the XFF header with only this value, and forwarding it along?

I really don't know much about nginx and its config usages but I saw that I could potentially use the `Map` function with some regex to extract the last value, but then I am not sure how to set the XFF header without also adding the ALB's ip to it?

This is how I think the map function would look look in the config.

```
map $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for $client_ip {"[^,]+$" $1;}
```

But I am not sure if that will also add the ALB's(previous hops) IP to that service? If so I want the second last IP?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, this is wrong:

> What I am using in the MicroService is the last IP in the XFF (X-Forwarded-For) header.

You don't need the last IP in the header but the first one indeed. By default, AWS ALB works in `append` mode and when in this mode, it appends any subsequent proxy/lb IPs to the last in a comma separated manner. So, the first or the leftmost IP in the `X-Forwarded-Header` is the client ip. See [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/x-forwarded-headers.html#x-forwarded-for).

In order to get the first entry in the header, you can use `map` in this fashion:

```
http {
  ...
  ...
  server {
    ...
    map "$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for" $client_ip_addr {
      (^((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1\d|[1-9]|)\d)\.?\b){4}),(.*)    $1;
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

The `$client_ip_addr` variable will contain the ip address of the client from where the request originated. You can pass this variable as `X-Forwarded-For` in any `location` block like this:

```
location / {
  ...
  proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $client_ip_addr;
  ...
}
```

If you're really concerned about XFF attacks, I'd recommend this for further reading:

- [`Using the Forwarded header`](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/forwarded/)

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but we have a security tests failing that injects XFF header, so we cant assume the first IP in the XFF is true. We need the IP appended by the ALB, which I believe after "$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for" is used it will be second to last correct? How would I do that?